# AWS XRay: Unable to write to /tmp/.aws-xray/initialized. Failed to signal SDK initialization

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I am trying to write a Lambda function to store data in dyanamodb and try to integrate with AWS Xray. Below is the code for Lambda function. I am getting the error

> Unable to write to /tmp/.aws-xray/initialized. Failed to signal SDK
>   initialization. Subsegment put_item discarded due to Lambda worker
>   still initializing

I install Aws xray SDK package. Also, begin segment and end segment are included in the code. and also set an environment variable of **LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT**. 
Please give a solution to this error.

```
import json
import os
import configparser
import boto3
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch

patch(['boto3'])
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['dynamodb_table'])

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for i in event:
        item = {
            'key': i['key'],
            'search': i['search'],
        }
        put_item_into_dynamodb(item)

    response = {
         "statusCode": 200,
         "body": json.dumps(item)
    }
    return response

def put_item_into_dynamodb(item):
    try:
        xray_recorder.begin_subsegment('put_item')
        response = table.put_item(Item=item)
        status_code = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']
        xray_recorder.current_subsegment().put_annotation('put_response', status_code)
    finally:
        xray_recorder.end_subsegment()
```

Update-2 (second problem) : in this code **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'put_annotation'** this error is coming .. i dont have any idea why this is coming..

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    val = (str(event['userId']),str(event['teamId']), str(event['searchScope']))
    key_table = "|".join(val)
    key = {
        'key': key_table
    }
    response = get_item_into_dynamodb(key)

    try:
        data = response['Item']
        for i in data['search']:
            keyword_list.append(i['searchText'])
            dict_of_keyword[i['searchText']] = i['dateTime']

        recent_sort = sorted(dict_of_keyword.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
def get_item_into_dynamodb(key):
    try:
        xray_recorder.begin_segment('get_item')
        response = table.get_item(Key = key)
        status_code = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']
        xray_recorder.current_subsegment().put_annotation('get_response', status_code) #error is on this line
    finally:
        xray_recorder.end_subsegment()

    return response
```

Comment: hii joey welcome to stackoverflow can you please post the full code here

Comment: please check i updated

Comment: does cloudwatch says on which line this error occurs ?

Comment: right now I am running on locally and this error is coming.

Comment: and when I just do patch and **Unable to write to /tmp/.aws-xray/initialized. Failed to signal SDK initialization** this error is showing,

Comment: If you are running it on local host you need to run xray demon   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-local.html

Comment: My advice is to test it online first if it works then you need to run xray deamon on localhost

Comment: @varnit it is working on remotely.

Comment: Then install xray daemon with the help of guide above

Comment: @varnit if **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'put_annotation'** this type of error coming then what is the reason behind it.

Comment: @varnit can you please see my updated question

Comment: On which line this error occurs ?

Comment: xray_recorder.current_subsegment().put_annotation('get_response', status_code)  on this line @varnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create segments within Lambda function. Lambda will create the segments in the outside wrapper which you cannot access within the function. Could you try to change from `xray_recorder.begin_segment('get_item')` to `xray_recorder.begin_subsegment('get_item')`?

Also the trace data generated outside of lambda handler will not be captured because during that time the lambda function is still initializing and no tracing context is available.

Comment: it works.. for the first code for  **xray_recorder.begin_subsegment('put_item')** do I need to change in this too?